# How can redirect back from child screen to parent screen using react-navigaor v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an Ancestor screen called **stacks** and I want to redirect back from the child screen called **AddCardScreen** to  **DetailScreen** with a **card** parameter however by printing **route.params.card** parameter values are undefined

Code from addCardScreen:

```
const submitCard =()=> {

    const card = {answer, question}  
    addCardToDecks(route.params.deckTitle, card).then(data => {
       //route.params.updateCard(card)
      navigation.navigate("stacks", {screen:"detail", params: {card: card}})

   }).catch(err=>alert(JSON.stringify(err)))
    }
```

Codes of the details screen

```
useEffect(()=>{
        if(route.params.card){
            setNewCard(route.params)
            console.log(`card ${JSON.srtringify(route.params.card)}`)
        }
    },[newCard, cards])
```

Comment: have you tried popToTop or Reset?

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName', { card: card, });`

to access card from next screen:

`this.props.route.params.card`

Because I'm using a functional component. I used **route.params.** and it works
My app is redirecting correctly with parameter however it is not updating without reloading whole Application